# How to display UIImage without having any stretching but all be the same height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am displaying images in a `UITableViewController` inside a cell, currently to show the full image I am setting the `UIImageView` as `aspectFit` but it doesn't fill up the entire `UIImageView`.

Is there a way, where I can show the full image and not distort it like the other `contentView` modes do?

Comment: use `ScaleAspectFill`.

Comment: when i do this, not the full image is shown inside the imageView, edges of the image are cut off.

Comment: Ofcource, you can only have pleasure of filling the image view or showing the right image. if image is not in same ratio as `imageView`.

Comment: is there a way i can fill the imageView fully and also keep ratio?

Comment: No sorry! Not possible mathematically!

Comment: how does instagram do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100150/discussion-between-rptwsthi-and-farhan).

Answer (score 0):

You should use as below :

```
Youreimageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

This is from the [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode) apple Document:

> - **UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit**
>
> The option to scale the content to fit the size of the view by
>   maintaining the aspect ratio. Any remaining area of the view’s bounds
>   is transparent.

For the Image showing in the Tableviewcell. You need to do customization of the UItableviewCell, and then you need to put imageview in that. That imageview must have this content mode to set image.

Comment: ive tried this but it makes the image too small, it keeps the ratio nice but i want it to fill the imageView

Comment: What exact output you want? if you tell me that then i can give you solution fro that. @farhan

Comment: basically, what i want to do is show the full image without distorting it or cropping the edges off.

Comment: or how can i set the uitableviewcell based on the height of the image?

Comment: You do understand that that is physically impossible. When the aspect ratio of the image is not equal to the aspect ratio of the ImageView, then you have to either 1) fill the view, but distort the image by changing its aspect ratio, 2) fill the view, but cut of parts of the image, or 3) not fill the view. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help :)

YourImageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
YourImageview.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: i know this works nicely, but it cuts off the image.